# Puppies coughing as if something is choking

Tags: dogs

I have been noticing the stray puppies I feed. 3 out of 4 of them frequently cough as if something is stuck in their windpipe or foodpipe. I feed them Marie biscuits which I think aren't the ones causing problems.

They eat from garbage. What can I do without a vet? They are fine but once in a while they start coughting.

Answer (score 3):

A number of things can cause coughing in dogs, not much you can do without a definitive diagnosis.

Some examples:

- Bordetella Bronchiseptica
- Fox lung worm
- Canine Influenza
- Pneumonia/Bronchitis
- Fungal infection
- Heartworm

Sometimes dogs will pick up a little viral infection that causes a cough and will go away over a course of 2 weeks.

I wouldn't worry about the biscuits getting stuck in their trachea, for the most part dogs can have a gag reflex from chewing sticks or bones that get stuck in their esophagus. For multiple puppies to have the same symptoms it's most likely viral or parasites.

Answer (score 0):

Humans have unique anatomy of the larynx in order to facilitate speech. Animals are much less likely to choke on food than a human is. The most likely explanation then, is that the puppies are ill with something that includes coughing as a symptom. I would take them for a checkup with the vet.

Comment: I cannot go to a vet. They cough with less sound 5-6 times, then loudly cough with mouth wide open. Is there anything I can do? They drink water but that doesn't seem to help.